# how can i get the size of an array so i can declare said array from a function

Tags: c++

```
    const int size = arraySize();
    int list[size];
```

I get the following error:

> expression must have a constant value

I know this may not be the best way to do it but it is for an assignment.

Comment: What is the definition of `arraySize`? If it can be `constexpr` then it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dynamic allocation of this array.

```
 int size = arraySize();
 int* list;
 list = new int [size];
```

It should work. 
In addition, there is a condensed explanation of how dynamic arrays works: [DynamicMemory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

PS. Remember to free memory that you dynamically allocated, when it won't be needed:

```
delete [] list;
```

Comment: I am not sure this is the answer Omar was looking for. Since he seems to want to use his function `arraySize()`?

Comment: This code still use arraySize() function, because size is equal to return of arraySize().

Comment: Should use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that in C++ there are no dynamically allocated arrays.

Also, `const` variables are not necessarily known at compile time!

You can do one of the following:

1. Declare the function `arraySize` as `constexpr`, assuming you can calculate its value at ***compile time***, or create a constant (again, with `constexpr`) which represents the array size.
2. Use dynamically allocated objects, such as `std::vector` (which is an "array" that can expand), or pointers. However, note that when you are using pointers, you must allocate its memory by using `new`, and deallocate using `delete`, which is error prone. Thus, I suggest using `std::vector`.

Using the first one, we get:

```
constexpr std::size_t get_array_size()
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = get_array_size();
    int list[size];
}
```

which compiles perfectly.

Another thing which is nice to know is that there is `std::array` which adds some more functionality to the plain constant-size array.